# How to run a mixed C++/Fortran project under Eclipse IDE?

Tags: c++, eclipse, fortran, photran

I was trying to compile a mixed programming lanaguage (C++/Fortran) sample project provided by Intel Compiler 2013 under **Eclipse IDE**. I can run this project successfully under Visual Studio IDE (on Windows OS system), but I have not figured out how to run the same project under Eclipse on Linux. The configuration of linking the Fortran to the C++ project in Eclipse IDE is the main issue that troubles me.

Could anyone please tell me how to link these two projects? Thanks. The output should be simple "Testing...123."

Li

---

The source codes are as follows: 
(1) the main program, fmain.f90

```
PROGRAM fmain
USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING
IMPLICIT NONE
INTERFACE
SUBROUTINE c_routine (int_arg, str_in, str_out, str_out_len) BIND(C)
IMPORT ! Use declarations from host  
INTEGER(C_INT), VALUE,INTENT(IN) :: int_arg
    CHARACTER(KIND=C_CHAR), DIMENSION(*), INTENT(IN) :: str_in
    CHARACTER(KIND=C_CHAR), DIMENSION(*), INTENT(OUT) :: str_out  
    INTEGER(C_INT), VALUE, INTENT(IN) :: str_out_len
END SUBROUTINE c_routine
END INTERFACE
CHARACTER(80) OUTPUT_TEXT
INTEGER IN_ARG, OUTPUT_LEN
CHARACTER(80) INPUT_TEXT
INPUT_TEXT = "Testing..."//C_NULL_CHAR 
IN_ARG = 123
CALL c_routine (IN_ARG, INPUT_TEXT, OUTPUT_TEXT, LEN(OUTPUT_TEXT))
OUTPUT_LEN = INDEX(OUTPUT_TEXT," ")
IF (OUTPUT_LEN == 0) OUTPUT_LEN = len(OUTPUT_TEXT)
WRITE (*,*) OUTPUT_TEXT(1:OUTPUT_LEN)
END
```

(2) csub.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C" void c_routine (
    int int_arg, // integer to convert
    char* input_text, // text to prepend to converted integer
    char* output_text, // output buffer
    int output_text_len // length of output buffer
    )

{
sprintf_s(output_text,output_text_len,"%s%i ",input_text,int_arg);
}
```

Comment: A possible workaround: Is there an option to create a makefile project?

Comment: @Stefan, I knew this method you suggested but I am just curious about how to make Eclipse IDE be able to handle this mixed language project as visual studio did on my desktop (it takes only a few steps to tell visual studio to perform the mixed language compilation). Thanks for replying to my question.